# How do I specify that I am returning a vector of 4 Int32 in a function?

Tags: julia

If I want to specify that my function returns a Bool I do:

```
function myfunc(a,b)::Bool
```

What if I want to specify that I will return a vector of 4 Int32 elements?

```
a = Vector{Int32}(undef, 4)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### You can't, and you don't have to.

The return type annotation is to declare the return type.

The length of a `Vector` is not part of its type.
it is part of its value, and it can change. (e.g. `push!` can be called on it).

Notice:

```
julia> typeof([1,2,3,4])
Array{Int64,1}
```

(`Vector{T}` is just a constant for  `Array{T,1}`)

So all you would do is delcare the type:

```
function myfunc(a,b)::Vector{Int}
```

Alternatively, you might want a `NTuple{Int,4}` i.e. a `Tuple{Int, Int, Int, Int}`,
or a `SVector{Int,4}` from [StaticArrays.jl](https://github.com/JuliaArrays/StaticArrays.jl)

---

In general return type annotation is not super useful.
It basically boils down to the code automatically calling `convert{RETURNTYPE, raw_return_value)`, which may error.
This can be helpful on occation for making your code type-stable, if you lose track of what types different are being returned from different return points (if you have multiple).

Rarely it might help the compiler type-infer. (Since `convert` always returns the indictated target type).

Some argue this serves a documentation purpose also.

Comment: There is also the `Size` trait in StaticArrays, which may or may not be of help. It can be used to annotate ordinary arrays with size information, but I don't know if you can use it for return type annotation. I, too, question the necessity of return type annotation in most normal cases, maybe the OP can clarify the need.

Comment: Same as specifying the type of the parameters might help to detect issues (if I understood it correctly) I thought it might be good to specify the return type. Also as mentioned in the accepted answer, it is easier to understand what function does when you actually see what it is returned in the function definition -i.e. documentation purposes-.

Comment: Also, the idea of using a Tuple might make much more sense here. Thanks for the advice.